# Seeking oceanographical/environmental data for Arctic (Baffin Bay/Davis Strait area)

Tags: raster, data

I am looking for oceanographical/environmental variables that are available for Baffin Bay/Davis Strait area over the time period of 1995-2011, however, I am not familiar with oceanographical/environmental datasets.

Perhaps some of you may be able to point me in the right direction.
Which oceanographical/environmental variables/layers are available from this part of the world and for which time period?

Where can I access these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a bit of NASA data pertaining to fisheries and Zooplankton:
http://iobis.org/mapper/?resource_id=50

Answer (score 1):

The following National Oceanographic Data Center (NODC) link from [NOAA](http://www.nodc.noaa.gov/General/NODC-About/NODC-Major-Products.html) would be a good start.

GIS data in vector format (surface temperature data for 1981 - 2009) for the Arctic region can be found [here](http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2011/1246/downloads.html).